# Python Linked API throwing error with Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, linkedin-api

This code to fetch skills from linkedin is working fine with python 2.6

```
from linkedin import helper
from liclient import LinkedInAPI
import json
AUTH_TOKEN='{"oauth_token_secret": "TOKEN SECRET", "oauth_authorization_expires_in": "0", "oauth_token": "OAUTH TOKEN", "oauth_expires_in": "0"}'
consumer_key = 'CONSUMER KEY'
consumer_secret = 'CONSUMER SECRET'
APIClient =LinkedInAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
request_token = APIClient.get_request_token()
field_selector_string = ['skills']
results = APIClient.get_user_profile(json.loads(AUTH_TOKEN), field_selector_string)
Skills = results[0].skills
print  Skills
```

But when I run same code with python 2.7 gettting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "linkedintest.py", line 10, in <module>
results = APIClient.get_user_profile(json.loads(AUTH_TOKEN), field_selector_string)
File "/var/www/shine/liclient/__init__.py", line 82, in get_user_profile
resp, content = client.request(url, 'GET')
File "/var/www/shine/liclient/oauth2/__init__.py", line 603, in request
req.sign_request(self.method, self.consumer, self.token)
File "/var/www/shine/liclient/oauth2/__init__.py", line 357, in sign_request
self['oauth_signature'] = signature_method.sign(self, consumer, token)
File "/var/www/shine/liclient/oauth2/__init__.py", line 683, in sign
hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 133, in new
return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 72, in __init__
self.outer.update(key.translate(trans_5C))
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from linkedin import helper
from liclient import LinkedInAPI
import json
AUTH_TOKEN='{"oauth_token_secret": "TOKEN SECRET", "oauth_authorization_expires_in": "0", "oauth_token": "OAUTH TOKEN", "oauth_expires_in": "0"}'

# converting unicode dict to str dict
AUTH_TOKEN=json.loads(AUTH_TOKEN)
AUTH_TOKEN_DICT = {}
for auth in AUTH_TOKEN:
    AUTH_TOKEN_STR[str(auth)] = str(AUTH_TOKEN[auth])


consumer_key = 'CONSUMER KEY'
consumer_secret = 'CONSUMER SECRET'
APIClient =LinkedInAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
request_token = APIClient.get_request_token()
field_selector_string = ['skills']

results = APIClient.get_user_profile(AUTH_TOKEN_DICT, field_selector_string)
Skills = results[0].skills
print  Skills
```